# VSCode editor mouse cursor inverts color when moving across panes

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I just upgraded to Windows 11 with a fresh install, and a fresh install of VSCode. I have never seen this behavior prior to now. I have panes open side-by-side, each with various files open.  When moving the mouse across the divider between open panes (or whatever they're called in VSCode), the mouse cursor goes temporarily from black to white (or some pseudo-white color). It reverts to black after a few seconds. A white cursor against an off-white background is very hard to see, and the cursor seems to disappear during these few seconds.  I tried to record a screencast via the Snipping Tool, but I cannot reproduce the issue when recording :(

If I move the mouse very slowly, I can avoid this. In moving it slowly I see that the mouse cursor changes as it crosses over the scroll bar and the vertical line for pane sizing.

Is there a setting to block this?  Is it a bug?  I cannot find any other reports of this issue online.

VSCode help/about:

```
Version: 1.87.2 (user setup)
Commit: 863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6
Date: 2024-03-08T15:20:17.278Z
Electron: 27.3.2
ElectronBuildId: 26836302
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: @starball - I updated the question with my VSCode help/about info and sorry for the caret/cursor confusion, it's the mouse cursor, but it's in the shape of an I-beam text cursor aka caret.  I'll look into the extensions shortly.  Thanks.

Comment: Of course after several days of seeing this, as I go to reload w/o extensions the problem is not manifesting.  I'll see what the story is when I reboot tomorrow. I was also noticing that with two VSCode windows open it was only happening in the first one opened.

Comment: please do an extension bisect. that should reveal an extension causing the problem unless it's due to a combination of multiple extensions, or a restart is required to repro the issue after changing which extensions are enabled, in which case you need to manually disable/enable extension when starting VS Code via commandline (see the output of `code --help`)

Comment: Wow, after several days of living with this oddity, this morning it is gone.  I never restarted w/o extensions.  Never needed to.  I only have 3 extensions anyway, ESLint, Markdown theme, and Visual Studio Keymap.

Comment: It's back... I just reloaded w/o extensions and the issue persists, so it's not one of my three extensions. It reappeared in the middle of today's session. I can't say exactly when it returned. I'll try to be aware of any accidental keystrokes or whatever else might happen prior to it appearing and disappearing again.  @starball -please let me know if there's anything else I can try.